# $x^b-1$ and $x^b+1$ in different bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm a designer doing a project on numbers expressed in different base systems and am wondering why I'm running into so many prime factors ending in $1$. Here are $4$ conjectures I've created as a result of my playing. Any explanations as to why this is happening would be much appreciated.

**x=any whole number**

**b=any base number** (example: when $b=2$ answer is written in binary, when $b=7$ answer is written in base $7$, when $b=37$ answer written in base $37$, and so on)

**For both $x^b-1$ and $x^b+1$:**

1. will always result in largest prime factor $>x+1$ ending in the number $1$.
2. if $b$ is prime, all prime factors $>x+1$ will end in $1$.

**Only for $x^b+1$:**

3. if $b$ is any power of $2$, then all prime factors except $2$, will end in $1$.

**Only for $x^b-1$:**

4. if $b=2$*prime, all prime factors $>x+1$ will end in $1$.

Comment: Case $b=2$ is obvious... How far did you perform your computations for any base?

Comment: The largest I tested was b=101, x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I also tested a few larger b cases which were mostly with x=2 and x=3 (computing power starts to get slow after that), but they all worked.

Comment: One special case that might bring insight: all [prime factors of Mersenne numbers](https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/LukeMirror/lit/lit_027s.htm) are of the special form you noted.